# postMessage function not working with window.onload?

Tags: javascript

OK, so here's the setup. I have an expandable banner that swaps out the HTML of the smaller initial banner to the larger expanding banner. (In this test it expands from 160px wide to 600px wide.) I also have the second HTML page jump to a specific scene in my exported Tumult Hype (An HTML 5 animation program) files.

The function

> "postToHype()"

uses postMessage to pass off to the second HTML document HypeExample to tell it to open to the second scene of the document. So in theory, what happens is the ad not only expands and loads the second HTML document, but it also then jumps to the second scene in that document.

This is working for me; it triggers the "postToHype()" function when I mouseover the ad. This also works when I tested using a button which also triggers the

> "combine()"

function. The "combine()" function ALSO triggers the function

> "autoExpand()"

which opens the ad for 7 seconds and then closes it again.

What I can't get to work is having window.onload call the "combine();" function. When window.onload fires "combine()" , "autoExpand()" works but "postToHype()" does not. Why does the button click and onmouseover work with my "postToHype()" function, but "window.onload" does not?

Not all of the code is shown here (such as the linked .js libraries) but I tried to include the most pertinent bits. Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var exampleHTMLToPage = ExpandableBanners.banner("exampleHTMLToPage", "HypeExample.html", 600, 600);
        exampleHTMLToPage.setCloseImage("images/close.png", 'right', 'bottom');
        exampleHTMLToPage.animated = true;
        exampleHTMLToPage.setDirection('down', 'right'); 
        animated = true;
        exampleHTMLToPage.expandOnClick = false;
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){documentReady=true;
});}
else if (!window.onload) window.onload = function(){documentReady=true;}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function autoExpand() { 
setTimeout("ExpandableBanners.openAd('exampleHTMLToPage')",0000);
setTimeout("ExpandableBanners.closeAd('exampleHTMLToPage')",7000);
}
</script>

<script> function combine() {
autoExpand();
postToHype();
} </script>

<script>
function postToHype(){
document.getElementById('exampleHTMLToPage_expanded_media').contentWindow.postMessage(['start', 'Scene2'], '*')
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div onmouseover="postToHype()" id="exampleHTMLToPage" style="width:150px; height:600px; background-color:rgb(30,167,221); position:relative; color:white; font-weight:bold">
  <div style="display:inline-block; 
  width:140px; font-size:22px; margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;">This is an HTML banner RK V7. Click to see exported HYPE interactive that loaded inside.</div>
  </div>
<button onclick="combine();">Click me</button>
</body>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
  combine();
};</script>
```

Comment: What is target context of `postMessage`? An `iframe` element?

Comment: It is because you call a function that has not been loaded jet. Try to write the Combine() under postToHype()

Comment: @Zorken17 — I think you are confusing *defining* a function with calling it.

Comment: @Quentin thanks that was the word (defining) I was looking for.

Comment: @guest271314 It is created inside of an iFrame element. Thanks.

Comment: Is requirement to wait until `<iframe>` element is loaded before calling `postMessage` to `<iframe>`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. And once upon a time, I had my function looking like this just in case... but it still didn't help.    <script>
function postToHype(){
document.getElementById('exampleHTMLToPage_expanded_media').contentWindow.postMessage(['start', 'Scene2'], '*')
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",postToHype);
}
else if (!window.onload) window.onload = postToHype;
</script>

Comment: @Chirpie `window.onload` is referencing current `window`, not `<iframe>` `window`, `DOMContentLoaded` is referencing current `document`, not `<iframe>` `document`. Try calling `postMessage` to `<iframe>` element within `<iframe>` `onload` event handler

Comment: @guest271314 Good grief, of course! As a quick test, I did a dirty cheat and wrote <script>
setTimeout(function() { combine() },2000)
</script> to give it time to load. And tada! It's working now. Now I just need to clean it up and do it right. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change it lite this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function autoExpand() { 
  setTimeout("ExpandableBanners.openAd('exampleHTMLToPage')",0000);
  setTimeout("ExpandableBanners.closeAd('exampleHTMLToPage')",7000);
}  

function postToHype(){
  document.getElementById('exampleHTMLToPage_expanded_media').contentWindow.postMessage(['start', 'Scene2'], '*')
}

function combine() {
  autoExpand();
  postToHype();
} 

</script>
```

You need to defining the function postToHype() before you are calling it. And it is better to just use one script tag and write all your code in it.

Comment: I can't find anywhere which tries to call `postToHype` before it exists, so while that would make the code neater, I don't see it making any difference.

Comment: The window.onload calls combine() witch calls postToHype(). And if postToHype() is not loaded (defining) he will get an undefined value

Comment: Why wouldn't postToHype be loaded before the window's load event fires? The script that defines postToHype isn't being loaded dynamically.

Comment: @Quentin is right. I thought the same thing and tried this order as part of my trouble shooting. Still no joy. I do appreciate the idea. I agree it's better to write one script tag, and in fact at one point it was, but it's currently broken out like this for me to more easily pinpoint my issue.

Comment: Turns out the answer was the content of the iframe being created wasn't being jumped to because it hadn't loaded yet. I need to make the function for postToHype do a check for the inner content to be loaded. Thanks again everyone.